# How to Add image in footer of MS Word 2010 Addin?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I have added Image to my MS Word header in Addin using below code.

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape logoCustom = null;
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object oFalse = false;
            object oTrue = true;
            String logoPath = @"C:\Users\Hasan\Desktop\headers_footers\wordtemplate\logo_wordtemplate_150dpi.jpg";
            logoCustom = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddPicture(logoPath,
             ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            logoCustom.Select(ref oMissing);
            logoCustom.WrapFormat.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapNone;
            logoCustom.Left = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeLeft;

            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekMainDocument;
```

But i am having issues with Adding it in footers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
var range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.HeaderFooter.Range;
var inlineShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(sLogo, False, True, range);
var shape = inlineShape.ConvertToShape();
shape.Left = nHPos;
shape.Top = nVPos;
shape.Width = nWidth;
shape.Height = nHeight;
```

Also with .Net 4 the parameters are optional so you don't need all those oMissing arguments.

Comment: the code I pasted above is working fine for headers but I also want to add the image in footer. how I can do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific about the target Range for the graphical object you add. Using `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.HeaderFooter.Range` doesn't tell Word whether Header or Footer, so Word does what it thinks best.

To specify a Footer range:

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oFalse = false;
object oTrue = true;
Word.Section sec = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Sections[1];
Word.HeaderFooter ft = sec.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
Word.Range rngFooter = ft.Range;
object oRange = rngFooter;
Word.Shape LogoCustom = ft.Shapes.AddPicture(logoPath, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, 
                        ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, 
                        ref oRange);
```

Note that the approach using a `Range` object means you do *not* need the line with `SeekView`. Working with the Range directly will not change the selection, meaning the screen stays quieter and the code executes more quickly.

Comment: hey @cindy-meister thanks for reply but the thing is that 
`Word.Footer ft` is Word does not have any footer property. Can you please help ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, typo on my part: `Word.HeaderFooter ft`

Comment: hey but the code again adds the image in the header. can you recheck the code please ?

Comment: When you add a `Shape` object to a header *or* a footer it can be positioned anywhere on the page - it does not have to appear at the top/bottom of the page. Its *anchor* (the paragraph with which it is associated) will be in the specified location (header or footer). If it's appearing in the wrong place then you haven't set the `Top` property (and you may also need the `RelativeVerticalPosition` property in addition).

Comment: hey can you help me by writing down the exact code that adds the footer, i have tried but couldn't find a way to add it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you add your best try to the end of your Question, as an [edit]. Be very specific about what part of it is not working and HOW it's not working. We can then look at that.